# Strange behavior of unit test in CakePHP Test Suite 2.2

Tags: unit-testing, cakephp

I am the only one in my development team having this problems with the unit tests.
Either the debugger, nor a google /stackoverflow or my colleagues could help me.
On my machine the unit tests work 10% of the time. The rest of the time they run until they load a site not found page after a long long time.
I have tried everything:

- The entire cache is disabled
- I tried it out with two browsers
- Restarted Apache and MySQL
- Login to the app
- Debugging with Firebug

Nothing helps.
I have no clue what the problem is.
I'm running windows 8 over bootcamp for work. So there is not much installed (which could lead into side effects).

If I try it out several times, it will work by chance and pass all tests.

Comment: Deleting my answer because I don't know much about bootcamp.  Are your colleagues using bootcamp or are you the only one?!

Comment: About using a debugger:  don't bother.  Stepping through framework code won't get you anything but a headache.

Comment: I'm the only one but it should not have any effects. I'm also using Windows 8 while the rest are usin Windows 7 and one is using mac.

Comment: It is just an idea / feeling but I think it may be a problem with the authentication. But normally I should get an error than or not? It really borthers me, that there is not a single error message and I have absolute no power to find out what is going wrong.

Comment: Make sure Firebug is turned off, if you aren't using it.  It can interfere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The rest of the time they run until they load a site not found page
>   after a long long time.

Are you executing the tests in the browser? You should use the console over the web front end. Running the tests in the browser can be problematic.